# Chat/conversation database

Tags: database, hadoop, chat

For a personal interest I try to define a simulated AI who is based on information that he learned and internet search in order to give more details than what the system know.

I took the example of a child, when he's born he need to learn everything, he heard a lot and then propose some answers. His mom/dad tell him if the answer are suitable or not.

In order to do that I wanted to stock a lot of chat conversations in an hadoop system and parse all of those conversation in order to determine which are the most frequent answer given. With that I want to construct a neuronal database who contains conversations types with the determined answers.

So my question is can I find somewhere legally on the internet one or more chat/conversation database in any format? (file, database, csv, ...)

The most data I have the best my chance are to be able to determine correctly the answers ;)

Thanks for the help and cheers,
Frédéric

PS: English is not my mother tongue

Answer (score 5):

[There is a collection of conversational datasets](http://freeconnection.blogspot.hu/2016/04/conversational-datasets-for-train.html). Most of them are collected from publicly available sources. For you the most interesting ones could be the Santa Barbara corpus (although it's a transcript of speech conversations) or the movie dialog dataset.

Comment: Here is another comprehensive collection of datasets: https://breakend.github.io/DialogDatasets/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly comprehensive collection of human-human and human-machine text dialogue datasets, as well as audio dialogue datasets.
https://breakend.github.io/DialogDatasets/

Answer (score 1):

Credits goes to "Default picture"'s answer from above for the extensive library of Human-Human, Human-Machine sonversation resources at https://breakend.github.io/DialogDatasets/ including the Let’s Go dialogs from provided by **Research Center at CMU** https://github.com/DialRC/LetsGoDataset those resources are also used to train conversational agents at https://any.company/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have a Chat dataset is to generate on your own. You know what exactly you want. But IRC has some chat datasets that one of them has been used in [this](http://cs.brown.edu/~melsner/chat-manual.html) research.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My idea is to feed my system with chats and forums datas in order to be surprised by the answer given and to have a system who has more knowledge than me. I will also go see in direction of 4chan and reddit maybe I can find some forums/conversations archives there too.

Comment: I recommend you to create a crawler using Apache Nutch to have your data. Even if you find a dataset, it has been generated with other criteria and use cases.